# Create a new file and delete password protection

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following VBA to save a new file on my desktop:

```
Sub Files()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\testfile.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & "testfile.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False
MsgBox ("File saved successfully on desktop.")
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

My original file is proteced with a password. This protection should be deleted in the new file which is created using the VBA above.

For unprotecting the file I have the following VBA:

```
Sub Unprotection()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
b.Unprotect Password:="abc"
Next b
End Sub
```

However, i do not know how to enter this code into the procedure of creating the new file. I tried to go with the below code but it only runs in the original file and not in the new file I have created.

```
Sub Files()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\testfile.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & "testfile.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False
Call Unprotection
MsgBox ("File saved successfully on desktop.")
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False
End Sub
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest fix is to move Unprotection to the very start of your routine.
You don't need to reprotect because you close the calling workbook without saving the changes anyway.

```
Sub Files()
Call Unprotection ' unprotect calling workbook sheets
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\testfile.xlsm" ' save a copy with non-protected sheets
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & "testfile.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False ' open the new non-protected book
MsgBox ("File saved successfully on desktop.") ' Message
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False ' Close the calling workbook without saving the unprotected sheets
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I do not know why but when I go with SaveChanges = False somehow the original file is still saved without the protection. Only if I re-protect it again it works.

Comment: First time I tried it I thought you were right but it's because I forgot to save it with all sheets protected again. 2nd time I tried it, it worked fine.. make sure you have all protections on original file before saving and running!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to unprotect your original workbook you can pass the new workbook as a parameter to Unprotection:

```
Sub Files()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\testfile.xlsm"
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & "testfile.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False)
  Call Unprotection(wb)
  MsgBox ("File saved successfully on desktop.")
  ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False
End Sub

Sub Unprotection(wb As Workbook)
  Dim b As Worksheet
  For Each b In wb.Worksheets
    b.Unprotect Password:="abc"
  Next b
End Sub
```